# How to get absolute x and y co-ordinates of a view in android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm getting live preview from camera, converting it to bitmap and getting pixel color from view's centre. I tried view.getX() and view.getY() but it always gives 0,0. Here is my xml code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:text="Capture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onCapClick"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv5"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/square"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/iv5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
    android:background="@drawable/square"/>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv8"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/iv5"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:background="@drawable/square"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv6"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:background="@drawable/square"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv4"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv5"
    android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
    android:background="@drawable/square"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/iv5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
    android:background="@drawable/square"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv9"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/iv5"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:background="@drawable/square"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv5"
    android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/iv5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
    android:background="@drawable/square"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv7"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv5"
    android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/iv5"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:background="@drawable/square"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:text="Default"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textColor="#FFFF00"/>
```

Since getX and getY aren't working I have put values manually but then it becomes device specific. How to get X and Y values?
Here is my Class's code-

```
package com.example.sid.rcs20;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.renderscript.Element;
import android.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB;
import android.renderscript.Type;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class Cameras extends AppCompatActivity implements Camera.PreviewCallback{

private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
static int width, height;
private ImageView iv1, iv2, iv3, iv4, iv5, iv6, iv7, iv8, iv9;
private FrameLayout frameLayout;
private String p51 ,p52, p53, p54, p55;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
    iv4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv4);
    iv5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv5);
    iv6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv6);
    iv7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv7);
    iv8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv8);
    iv9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv9);


    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    Log.d("phone size", String.valueOf(width) + "\t" + String.valueOf(height));

    if (!checkCameraHardware(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "NO CAMERA DETECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();


        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

        List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
//Camera.Size size1 = sizes.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++) {

            Log.d("all sizes", String.valueOf(sizes.get(i).width) + "\t" + String.valueOf(sizes.get(i).width));
            if (sizes.get(i).width > size.width) {
                size = sizes.get(i);

            }


        }

        Log.d("size", String.valueOf(size.width) + "\t" + String.valueOf(size.width));

        params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);
        params.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);
        params.setExposureCompensation(0);
        params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        params.setJpegQuality(100);
        params.setRotation(90);

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);


        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);


        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        frameLayout.addView(mPreview);
    }
}


/**
 * Check if this device has a camera
 */
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    // this device has a camera
// no camera on this device
    return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
}

/**
 * A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object.
 */
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}


/**
 * Create a File for saving an image or video
 */


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }
}


@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {

    int frameHeight = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;
    int frameWidth = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
    Log.d("preview size", String.valueOf(frameWidth) + "\t" + String.valueOf(frameHeight));

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameWidth, frameHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Allocation bmData = renderScriptNV21ToRGBA888(
            this,
            frameWidth,
            frameHeight,
            bytes);
    bmData.copyTo(bitmap);
    Bitmap bmp2 = RotateBitmap(bitmap, 90);

    int pixel1 = bmp2.getPixel(145, 415);
    int pixel2 = bmp2.getPixel(365, 415);
    int pixel3 = bmp2.getPixel(585, 415);
    int pixel4 = bmp2.getPixel(145, 630);
    int pixel51 = bmp2.getPixel(365, 630);
    int pixel52 = bmp2.getPixel(306, 570);
    int pixel53 = bmp2.getPixel(425, 690);
    int pixel54 = bmp2.getPixel(425, 570);
    int pixel55 = bmp2.getPixel(306, 690);
    int pixel6 = bmp2.getPixel(585, 630);
    int pixel7 = bmp2.getPixel(145, 865);
    int pixel8 = bmp2.getPixel(365, 865);
    int pixel9 = bmp2.getPixel(585, 865);

    changeRect(pixel1, 1);
    changeRect(pixel2, 2);
    changeRect(pixel3, 3);
    changeRect(pixel4, 4);
    changeRect(pixel51, 51);
    changeRect(pixel52, 52);
    changeRect(pixel53, 53);
    changeRect(pixel54, 54);
    changeRect(pixel55, 55);
    changeRect(pixel6, 6);
    changeRect(pixel7, 7);
    changeRect(pixel8, 8);
    changeRect(pixel9, 9);

}


private void changeRect(int pixel, int num) {
    int r = Color.red(pixel);
    int g = Color.green(pixel);
    int b = Color.blue(pixel);

    ColorUtil colorUtil = new ColorUtil();
    String name = colorUtil.getColorNameFromRgb(r, g, b);

    String[] idAndOurName = getDrawableIdAndOurName(name);
    int d = Integer.parseInt(idAndOurName[0]);
    String ourName = idAndOurName[1];



    if (num == 1) {
        iv1.setImageResource(d);
    } else if (num == 2) {
        iv2.setImageResource(d);
    } else if (num == 3) {
        iv3.setImageResource(d);
    } else if (num == 4) {
        iv4.setImageResource(d);
    } else if (num == 51) {
        p51 = ourName;
    } else if (num == 52) {
        p52 = ourName;
    } else if (num == 53) {
        p53 = ourName;
    } else if (num == 54) {
        p54 = ourName;
    } else if (num == 55) {
        p55 = ourName;
        d = getDrawableId();
        iv5.setImageResource(d);
    } else if (num == 6) {
        iv6.setImageResource(d);
    } else if (num == 7) {
        iv7.setImageResource(d);
    } else if (num == 8) {
        iv8.setImageResource(d);
    } else if (num == 9) {
        iv9.setImageResource(d);
    }

    Log.d("Selected Color", String.valueOf(num) + "\t" + name);

}

private int getDrawableId(){
    int[] cA = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0};
    cA = getCount(p51 , cA);
    cA = getCount(p52 , cA);
    cA = getCount(p53 , cA);
    cA = getCount(p54 , cA);
    cA = getCount(p55 , cA);


    if (cA[0]>=2){
        return R.drawable.yellow;
    }
    else if (cA[1]>=2){
        return R.drawable.green;
    }
    else if (cA[2]>=2){
        return R.drawable.blue;
    }
    else if (cA[3]==5){
        return R.drawable.white;
    }
    else if (cA[5]>=1){
        return R.drawable.red;
    }
    else if (cA[4]>=2){
        return R.drawable.orange;
    }

    else
        return R.drawable.square;
}

private int[] getCount(String s, int[] countArray){
    switch (s) {
        case "y":
            countArray[0]++;
            break;
        case "g":
            countArray[1]++;
            break;
        case "b":
            countArray[2]++;
            break;
        case "w":
            countArray[3]++;
            break;
        case "o":
            countArray[4]++;
            break;
        case "r":
            countArray[5]++;
            break;
    }
    return countArray;
}

private String[] getDrawableIdAndOurName(String name){
    if (name.contains("Yellow")) {
        return new String[]{String.valueOf(R.drawable.yellow), "y"};
    }
    else if (name.contains("White")) {
        return new String[]{String.valueOf(R.drawable.white), "w"};
    }
    else if (name.contains("Green")) {
        return new String[]{String.valueOf(R.drawable.green), "g"};
    }
    else if (name.contains("Blue")) {
        return new String[]{String.valueOf(R.drawable.blue), "b"};
    }
    else if (name.contains("Red")) {
        return new String[]{String.valueOf(R.drawable.red), "r"};
    }
    else if (name.contains("Orange")) {
        return new String[]{String.valueOf(R.drawable.orange), "o"};
    }
    else return new String[]{"" , ""};
}

public Allocation renderScriptNV21ToRGBA888(Context context, int width, int height, byte[] nv21) {
    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB yuvToRgbIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));

    Type.Builder yuvType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs)).setX(nv21.length);
    Allocation in = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

    Type.Builder rgbaType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs)).setX(width).setY(height);
    Allocation out = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbaType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

    in.copyFrom(nv21);

    yuvToRgbIntrinsic.setInput(in);
    yuvToRgbIntrinsic.forEach(out);
    return out;
}

public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}


public void onCapClick(View view) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    frameLayout.setForeground(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
}
```

}

Please help me to get exact location of center of imageviews.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int test1[] = new int[2];    
contentsView.getLocationInWindow(test1); 
//Or
int test2[] = new int[2];  
contentsView.getLocationOnScreen(test2);
```

Comment: If i take center(of screen) point's co-ordinates and center imageview's co-ordinates, they are different